# Essbase System Login

Tags: hyperion, essbase

I'm new to the Hyperion Essbase and I'm using "**Hyp 6.5**". Whenever I login to the Excel it shows "Essbase System Login screen". So each time I've to enter

- Server Name
- User Name
- Password
- Application/Database

Is it possible to set those values as default. So it's not prompting again and again? or is there is any plug-in's to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility developed by the group at IN2HYPERION called "[Excel Essbase Add-in Ribbon](http://www.in2hyperion.com/page/Excel-Essbase-Add-In-Ribbon.aspx)" that will store this information.  It works as an Excel add-in and will store the server, app, database, and password for connections.  I'm not affiliated in any way to the site but I've used the tool for a couple years and find it to be useful and reliable.  You'll need to check if it works with your version of Essbase.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no password caching like you want. The only thing that it will store is the most recently used servers, but other than that you have to type in your user namne and password, and then it will pull up the list of Applications and Databases.